# What are benefits of using Docker on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, spring-boot

I am wondering what are benefits of using Docker to deploy my Spring Boot app on AWS EC2/ESB. Are there any?

Answer (score -1):

This is a very broad question but in short the advantages are that if built right, Docker can fully automate your deploy process, allowing you to autoscale and resolve failures quickly (by destroying faulty containers and launching new ones instead - ideally using an automated process).